# Is there a way to change the vertical axis on FullCalendar to something else?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the FullCalendar module in drupal 7, and don't want time, kind of want categories on there instead, so you could set an event in a certain category on a certain day. Is there a way to do this in drupal? Or some other, even hacky way to do it?

Example: You want to set Phil to get his car fixed under the Time Off category(vertical axis) on Thursday, June 20th or something.

Comment: Is there any reason to use FullCalendar when you don't need time in the first place?

Comment: It's perfect for everything I need except that aspect.